# Issue with query structure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement :

```
user id    full role                           
a123456    abcd:READ_ONLY     
a123456    fghi:READ_ONLY
```

My target is to get both the rows using distinct keyword:

I am using below query:

```
select distinct 
         user id,
         SUBSTR(full role, INSTR(full role, ':')+1) end as ROLE
from table
```

but i am only able to achieve one row only. Can you please help me with that.I dont want to remove distinct from query because there are lot of other roles available as well in which full role can be same.

```
a123456     READ_ONLY
a123456     READ_ONLY
```

Comment: Huh?  You want to use `select distinct`, but you don't want distinct rows.  I'm quite confused.

Comment: So, if there were an additional two rows for that user_id for some sort of other role, e.g. 'WRITE', you'd only want to return a single row for the 'WRITE' role, but two rows for the 'READ_ONLY' role?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a count would do what you want?

```
select user id,
       SUBSTR(full role, INSTR(full role, ':')+1) as ROLE,
       count(*) as num_times
from table 
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output all rows for specific roles, but only one row for others, you could do:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'a123456' user_id, 'abcd:READ_ONLY' full_role FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'a123456' user_id, 'fghi:READ_ONLY' full_role FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'a123456' user_id, 'zyxw:WRITE' full_role FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'a123456' user_id, 'vuts:WRITE' full_role FROM dual)
SELECT user_id,
       role
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT user_id,
                        SUBSTR(full_role, INSTR(full_role, ':') + 1) AS role,
                        CASE
                          WHEN SUBSTR(full_role, INSTR(full_role, ':') + 1) = 'READ_ONLY' THEN
                           rownum
                          ELSE
                           NULL
                        END rn
        FROM   your_table)
ORDER BY user_id, ROLE;

USER_ID ROLE
------- --------------
a123456 READ_ONLY
a123456 READ_ONLY
a123456 WRITE
```

This seems a bit odd, though; I'd be interested to hear more about why you need this.